# Trigger no me esta reconociendo los valores enviados por NEW

Tags: mysql, trigger

El caso es que estoy realizando un trigger para que actúe a modo de espejo en otra tabla, sin embargo no esta funcionando como deberia.
Aqui os dejo el trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER new_loaner_added 
AFTER INSERT ON 'total_loaner' for each row
begin
    INSERT INTO NuevaVisita (not_cliente, not_fecha, not_act, ofi, not_fecha_proxima, not_tipo, not_estado, not_motivo, not_usuarioactu, not_horainicio, not_horafin, not_despacho) VALUES (NEW.idpaciente, CURDATE(), '1', '1', '2017-09-12', '1', '1', 'ALGO', 'NADIE', '09:00', '10:00', '1')
END;
```

El tema esta en que el NEW.idpaciente no lo esta recuperando y me llega un valor 0. Con los otros campos del trigger me pasa lo mismo siempre que utilice NEW.campo.

Seguiré insistiendo a ver si doy con la solución, entre tanto agradeceria cualquier información que me pueda proporcionar la comunidad.

Comment: yo quiero creer que esa tabla tiene los campos que estas buscando no? por si acaso, la muestras?

Comment: Si, los campos de la tabla coinciden con los que deseo insertar. De hecho tengo otro trigger con la sentencia update que funciona sin problemas. Edito: la sentencia insert tambien funciona correctamente con valores preestablecidos, solo me pasa con el NEW.idpaciente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿Al crear el disparador (trigger) no generar un error?, en mi prueba, genera un error la linea: `AFTER INSERT ON 'total_loaner' for each row`:

```sql
mysql> DELIMITER //

mysql> CREATE TRIGGER `new_loaner_added`
    -> AFTER INSERT ON 'total_loaner' FOR EACH ROW
    -> BEGIN
    ->   INSERT INTO `NuevaVisita` (`not_cliente`)
    ->   VALUES (NEW.`idpaciente`);
    -> END//
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
                    corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax
                    to use near ''total_loaner' FOR EACH ROW
                    BEGIN
                      INSERT INTO `NuevaVisita` (`not_cliente`)
                      ' at line 2

mysql> DELIMITER ;
```

Luego de solventar el problema, cambiar:

```
'total_loaner'
```

por

```
`total_loaner`
```

todo funciona como se espera:

```sql
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 5.7.11    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `NuevaVisita`, `total_loaner`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `total_loaner` (
    ->   `idpaciente` SERIAL
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `NuevaVisita` (
    ->   `not_cliente` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER //

mysql> CREATE TRIGGER `new_loaner_added`
    -> AFTER INSERT ON `total_loaner` FOR EACH ROW
    -> BEGIN
    ->   INSERT INTO `NuevaVisita` (`not_cliente`)
    ->   VALUES (NEW.`idpaciente`);
    -> END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;

mysql> INSERT INTO `total_loaner` SELECT NULL;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT `idpaciente`
    -> FROM `total_loaner`;
+------------+
| idpaciente |
+------------+
|          1 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT `not_cliente`
    -> FROM `NuevaVisita`;
+-------------+
| not_cliente |
+-------------+
|           1 |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Ver [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bHxCWaPzWTnfN11WRDB5jY/0).

Comment: Gracias por el seguimiento. El trigger funciona como debería funcionar, el fallo estaba en que se ejecutaba cuando no era ya que actuaba en conjunto con un plugin y, debido al propio funcionamiento de este, siempre insertaba una fila vacía (o con ciertos campos vacíos). La solución a la que llegue fue la de crear un trigger para que insertara una fila vacía en la otra tabla y a partir de ahí actuaba el trigger de update (que como he comentado antes si que funciona). Igualmente +1 por las molestias. Si pica la curiosidad el plugin es el Scheduler 4.4 de DHTMLX